# Returning exceptions with traceback

Tags: python, exception

I want to save exception in one function, and raise it on upper levels of call stack, but it's not possible. Saving exception with try/except clause doesn't save traceback

Next code:

```python
def saving_exception() -> SyntaxError:
    # try:
        raise SyntaxError('Exception')
    # except SyntaxError as e:
    #     return e


def middle_function() -> SyntaxError:
    exception = saving_exception()
    return exception


if __name__ == '__main__':
    raise middle_function()
```

Returns 3 frames:

1. <module>
2. middle_function
3. saving_exception

Uncommenting 3 lines in `saving_exception()` will return 2 frames:

1. <module>
2. saving_exception

Also `return e.with_traceback(sys.exc_info()[2])` in `saving_exception()` do the same as `return e`

How to make `saving_exception()` return exception with 3 frames without big changes outside?

Comment: Can you better describe what yiu mean by "saving exception"?

Comment: return exception

Comment: Return as many times as needed. I want transfer message and traceback up in the call stack